# How to make an elbow curve from term document(tf_idf) matrix?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, k-means, tf-idf

I tried the following piece of code to get elbow curve from tfidf_matrix (Which is a term document frequency matrix). But I'm getting the error as shown.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
What can be done to resolve this?

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

K = range(1,50)
KM = [KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(tfidf_matrix) for k in K]
centroids = [k.cluster_centers_ for k in KM]

D_k = [cdist(tfidf_matrix, cent, 'euclidian') for cent in centroids]
cIdx = [np.argmin(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
dist = [np.min(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
avgWithinSS = [sum(d)/tfidf_matrix.shape[0] for d in dist]

# Total with-in sum of square
wcss = [sum(d**2) for d in dist]
tss = sum(pdist(tfidf_matrix)**2)/dt_trans.shape[0]
bss = tss-wcss

kIdx = 10-1
```

tfidf_matrix is the term document frequency matrix we got from our documents.
[This is the error](https://pastebin.com/tBGuxhjZ)

Comment: please post the code and traceback as text and not as screenshot